# What is the real use case for .Any() on arrays?

Tags: linq

It clearly seems like I miss something very known and common but I can’t get why empty  .Any()  invocation on array and list differs in result.

As I know when I call .Any() it’s semantically equals of asking: "Does this box contain any items?". So when I write something like this:

```
List<int> list= new List<int>();

WriteLine(list.Any());//returns false



list.Add(1);

WriteLine(list.Any());//returns true
```

It expectedly returns false in the first case because list was empty and true when the item was added.

But further if I’ll try to use array instead and this array will be just initialized but empty (without any items) . Any() call will return true:

```
int[] arr = new int[2];

WriteLine(arr.Any());//returns true despite in has no items
```

So what’s the point to call empty .Any() on array to check if it has any items inside if it will always return true? Should I avoid use .Any() for such kind of purpose?

What’s the real use case of empty .Any call on array?

Comment: Arrays are initialised with default type values, which in int's case is 0.

Comment: your array was initialized with 2 elements, so it is not empty

Comment: So whats the point to call. Any() on array? What it does then? Should it be avoided completely?

Comment: @Andy: A use case, I can think of is, when a method returns an array, then you can do an Any() call on the result of the method as you don't know if the returned array contains any elements or not!

Comment: @Andy - An array is an enumerable so you can always call `.Any()`. Besides you can write `int[] arr = new int[0];` and then `arr.Any()` is `false`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your code example, there is no meaningful use case for Any() method on an initialized array.

But, as I mentioned in the comment to your question, if you are calling a method which returns an array, then you can perform an Any() check on the returned array to determine, if it has got any elements.

Comment: Thanks, that make sense.

Answer (score 2):

When you create an array, all elements are initialized with default values.
So, `int[] arr = new int[2]` is actually equal to `int[] arr = new int[2] { 0, 0 }`. That's why `.Any()` returns `true`.

Comment: Oleksander is correct. This is because basic types (And structs) must have a value, unlike classes that can have null instead.

Comment: So we should never use. Any()  on arrays and its actually useless on arrays because it will always return true, right?

Comment: @Andy - No, `int[] arr = new int[0];` will let `arr.Any()` return `false`.

Comment: Thanks everyone who replied.